# UML Activity Diagram Swimlanes - Does it matter where the final state ends?

Tags: uml, state, activity-diagram

I've built an activity diagram with a number of Swimlanes. I am curious to know if it matters where the Final State ends? http://i.imgur.com/SleQlks.png

Currently, seen from the picture the final state ends in the Technical Support Manager Swimlane. Would it matter if I made it finish in 'Computer' or another? Is there a general rule where it should finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you do not have any general rule about it but as I understand your diagram the Technical Support Manger is, at the end, in charge or the synchronization and closure of the flow.

Comment: Thanks [once again] again for your help!